# Get current directory when running remote batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Hello I have the following batch file saved to a location called `C:\.alias`. I added this directory to the path so that I can run all my custom scripts. I have tried creating a script to open a file in Chrome. When I am in another directory e.g. `C:\code\python` I call my script: `chrome.cmd text.svg` but Chrome tries to open: `file:///C:/.alias/test.svg`. Is there a way to prepend current path to the filename argument? Thanks.

**chrome.cmd**

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %~dp0%1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%~dp0` is the path to the location of the batch file.

`%cd%` is the current working directory.

This is what you need:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %cd%\%1
```

Comment: So I see. I was testing from `C:\ `, and when that is the working directory, `%cd%` includes the trailing `\ `.